# HTML - How to use title attributes as a tooltips for different portions of an image

Tags: html

I have an image with different objects inside.
Is there a way that I can associate different title attributes to different objects inside this image?

Thank you

//// I have found a solution for this question ////

```
Here is what we can do:
1> Add a DIV with an image as its background
2> Add a sub DIV inside this image DIV
3> Position this sub DIV
4> Change the title properties of this sub DIV.
```

Comment: I know you can do this with HTML5, not sure about the browsers support tho.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) with a `title` attribute on `area` element:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" usemap="#planetmap" />
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect"   coords="0,0,82,126" title="Sun"     href="sun.htm"    />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3"    title="Mercury" href="mercur.htm" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8"   title="Venus"   href="venus.htm"  />
</map>
```

For some reason, `alt` attribute doesn't works on Chrome as a tooltip.

Comment: You probably mean the `alt` attribute of the `area` tag.

Comment: @Gert I don't think browsers were ever mean to show `alt` as a tooltip - that was IE being IE.

Comment: Quite correct about alt and title. According to the W3 specs, "alt" is a "text equivalent" shown instead of an image, while "title" is "advisory information" shown in addition to an image. It is basically a bug if browsers show alt as tooltip.